# Is there a way to put conditions on listing via mapping on nhibernate 2.2?

Tags: .net, xml, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm working on a legacy system for which the code has no documentation and follows no patterns.

Some parts of the system do queries like `session.Query<Entity>();`, other parts do `Repository.GetAll();`.

The code that uses Repository is organized and I don't have any problem there, but the part that uses session is a mess, there is a lot of logic and queries in the controllers for almost every entity.

Recently we needed to make a change in one entity and add an column called `active`.

MyClass.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">

<class name="my_class" table="my_class" lazy="true">
    <id name="Id" column="id" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
    <generator class="native">
        <param name="sequence">sq_my_class</param>
    </generator>
    </id>
    
    <property column="name" type="String" name="Name" not-null="true" length="200" />
    <property column="area" type="Double" name="Area" not-null="true" />
    <property column="type" type="Int32" name="Type" not-null="true" />
    <property column="fiscalization" type="Boolean" name="Fiscalization" not-null="true" />         
    <property column="active" type="Boolean" name="Active" not-null="true" />
</class>
```

I want to prevent listing any object that is not activated, but I don't want to search the entire code for queries on this entity because I'm afraid of leaving something behind, instead, I wanted to know if I can do this via mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `where="active = 1"` on `class` element:

```xml
<class name="my_class" table="my_class" lazy="true" where="active = 1" >
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Actually i used ```where="active"```, `with ```where="active = 1"``` i was getting error of incompatible types.